# "error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'." when running gulp

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, gulp, typescript-typings

I'm new to Angular2, so i tried to install [this project](https://github.com/mathck/ng2Mvc5Demo/tree/fcc5a5826aea00b1114ef121faeba4dcf732879b).
I followed the steps in the readme.
This was the output of `typings install`:

```
typings install
typings WARN deprecated 2016-10-25: "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255" is deprecated (updated, replaced or remov
ed)
typings WARN deprecated 2016-9-14: "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759" is deprecated (updated, replaced or remove
d)
typings WARN deprecated 2016-11-21: "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046" is deprecated (updated, replaced or removed)


+-- core-js (global)
+-- jasmine (global)
`-- node (global)
```

This is the output when running gulp:

```
[10:24:40] Using gulpfile ~\Source\Workspaces\angularExample\ng2Mvc5Demo\ng2Mvc5Demo\Gulpfile.js
[10:24:40] Starting 'scriptsNStyles'...
[10:24:40] Finished 'scriptsNStyles' after 6.31 ms
[10:24:40] Starting 'ts'...
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'node'.
[10:24:45] TypeScript: 1 options error
[10:24:45] TypeScript: 1 emit error
[10:24:45] TypeScript: emit failed
[10:24:45] Finished 'ts' after 4.98 s
[10:24:45] Starting 'watch.ts'...
[10:24:45] Finished 'watch.ts' after 6.96 ms
[10:24:45] Starting 'watch'...
[10:24:45] Finished 'watch' after 3.4 μs
[10:24:45] Starting 'default'...
[10:24:45] Finished 'default' after 2.27 μs
```

typings.json:

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

typings/index.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="globals/core-js/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/jasmine/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
```

The typing files for "node" got created, just like the other two modules. But gulp (and VS when compiling) still say they can't find the type definition file.

I suspect the "`--" in front of "node" in the `typings install` output should tell me something, but I couldn't find any documentation on the output of this command.

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: `npm i -D @types/node`

Comment: Remove `typings`. It's deprecated for typescript 2. Use `@types/*`